# Is there a way to shorten the following code into one if statement?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
if (!isFinishing()) {
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
         if (!isDestroyed()) {
              showScoreScreenFragment(chronoText);
         }
     } else {
          showScoreScreenFragment(chronoText);
     }
}
```

That I need write before I'm committing fragment transactions. Is there a way to make this test in one if statement instead of 3?

because this:

```
if (!isFinishing() && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 && !isDestroyed())
```

doesn't have the same meaning.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do it? It reduces readability and hence maintainability greatly !! One liners are good for teasers but are catastrophic for release quality code specially with multiple developers contributing at the same time
Also no matter however cryptic you write at the high level lang, at the byte code level it's the same thing

Comment: You can reduce this, but it ain't pretty.

Comment: @Jason to what?

Comment: `if(!isF() && ((SDK_INT >= MR1 && !isD()) || SDK_INT < MR1))`

Comment: @Selvin note that testing `SDK_INT >= MR1` and `SDK_INT < MR1` isn't necessary. If `SDK_INT < MR1` is true, you don't need to evaluate the other operand (unless `isD()` has a side effect); if it is false, then `SDK_INT >= MR1` is true, so you only need to evaluate `!isD()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to shorten the code to one line (but please read on after the snippet):

```
if (!isFinishing() && (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 || !isDestroyed())) showScoreScreenFragment(chronoText);
```

**WARNING**

Please don't do this unless it is absolutely necessary. Coding like this makes the meaning of the code snippet almost impossible to understand, which in turn makes maintenance (where the majority of software development costs lie) much harder and therefore much more expensive.

Comment: I assumed that `howScoreScreenFragment` was a different method from `showScoreScreenFragment`.

Comment: I thought it was a typo.

Comment: possibly; probably. Maybe still worth clarifying.

Comment: it was a type, my mistake.

Comment: Edited to include @AndyTurner 's more efficient `||` section.

Answer (score 2):

I would keep it as 2 conditions:

```
if (!isFinishing()) {
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1
             || !isDestroyed()) {
         showScoreScreenFragment(chronoText);
     }
}
```

Note that the first operand of the `||` is the complement of the condition in the question.

Comment: Yeah, you are right... this is probably what I will go with... the one liner here is a mess, yet I will need to credit Jason for his answer, because it answers the question that was asked in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

There are three conditions you're checking, but like you pointed out you can't have them all in one if statement because they are sequential sensitive.

Depending on how you intend for the program to flow maybe there is a way to combine `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)` and `if (!isDestroyed())`. If they are both true you don't do anything. Is that intended?

But yeah, I don't see a good way to reduce this and still get the same semantics.

EDIT: Now that you fixed the typo ignore the above!

Comment: I need to first condition to be true in order to be able to run the isDestroyed method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only possible solution

```
if (!isFinishing() && (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1|| !isDestroyed())) {
showScoreScreenFragment(chronoText);
}
```

Comment: Why is this different from Jason's answer?

Comment: It's the same :/ i was answering when he posted his answer so i didn't read it